# Close jQuery thickbox on button click

Tags: jquery, thickbox

Here is my jQuery:

```
<script src="../js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/thickbox.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"

$('#button').click(function(){
     $('#TB_window').fadeOut();
});

</script>
```

Html:

```
  <input type="submit" id="button" value="clse" >
```

I tried this function, but it's not working.

Comment: Thickbox have their built in method. `tb_remove` just call this method `tb_remove();` wherever you need. It will close thickbox properly. read more my answer written below . http://stackoverflow.com/a/21216272/1124612

Answer (score 6):

Thickbox have their built in method. `tb_remove` just call this method `tb_remove();` wherever you need. It will close thickbox properly.

If you use `$('#TB_window').fadeOut();` , TB_overlay DIV will remain open. If you again do something nonsense like `$('#TB_overlay').fadeOut();` then it will create problem for your thickbox. And thickbox will stop function.

Comment: One line to do it: `$('#TB_window, #TB_overlay').fadeOut();`

Comment: Note that if modal=true, `tb_remove()` should be called from within the thickbox content. For example, `<div id="myThickbox"><button onclick="tb_remove();">X</button></div>` .

Answer (score 4):

You have to prevent the execution of the default event of the input.
Change your code to this:

```
$('#button').click(function(){
     $('#TB_window').fadeOut();
     e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Add an alert() so you can check of the function is executed at all. Also print out the result of $('#TB_window') to see if this selection returns a valid result.

Comment: Probably better if you use an `e.preventDefault()`. [Stop misusing return false](http://fuelyourcoding.com/jquery-events-stop-misusing-return-false/).

Answer (score 4):

This solution worked for me, try it:

```
$(document).ready(function{
  $('#button').click(function(){
   self.parent.tb_remove();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are including thickbox.js, which is obvious, than try.....

```
$('#closeTBWindow').click(tb_remove);
```

Comment: I love this sloution because it allows to reopen if clicked.
the updated code should be:
`$('#TB_closeWindowButton').click();`

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using "button" instead of "submit", like:

```
<input type="button" id="button" value="close" />
```

Then the jQuery code should be:

```
$(document).ready(function{
  $('#button').click(function(){
   $('#TB_window').fadeOut();
  });
});
```

Like this, you don't need to use `e.preventDefault()`.
The `$(document).ready()` part is really inportant. Without this jQuery would try to attach the code to the button before it even exists, thus won't work.

side-note: I like to use DIV elements as buttons.