# How do I call a javascript function in a PHP generated script?

Tags: php, javascript, function

I have one problem. I have a popup and after a user creates a room in the popup, I want to close that popup and then redirect the opener window to a new url. I have the function and everything, except for I do not know how to call the function. (Below I have written where I want the function to load).

Thanks

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
 function CloseAndRefresh() 
  {
opener.location.href = "<?php echo $website_url; ?>/livechat.php?idim=<?php echo $perdorusi2; ?>&room=<?php echo $emri; ?>";
opener.focus();
self.close();
  }
</script>
<?php
        include_once('db.php');

$perdoruesi = $_GET['perdoruesi']; 
if( strlen($_SESSION['id']) > '0' ) { $perdorusi2 = $_SESSION['id']; } else { $perdorusi2 = $perdoruesi; }

function makeRandomString($max=8) {
    $i = 0; 
    $possible_keys = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    $keys_length = strlen($possible_keys);
    $str = ""; 
    while($i<$max) {
        $rand = mt_rand(1,$keys_length-1);
        $str.= $possible_keys[$rand];
        $i++;
    }
    return $str;
}

$emri = makeRandomString();


$hidhnedb = mysql_query("INSERT INTO dbname(`row1`, `row2`) VALUES(NULL, '$emri')");

if($hidhnedb) { 

$max=count($_SESSION['mysession']);
$i = $max + 1;
$_SESSION['mysession'][$i][$emri] = $emri;

?>
***Here is the the place where I want to call the javascript function but I do not know how to do that.***
<?php
} else { echo "Error!"; } 


?>
```

Comment: Careful.  Always use `json_encode()` around any variable data used in the context of JavaScript, so that data is escaped correctly.  And while it doesn't matter in this specific instance, I highly recommend using prepared/parameterized queries with PDO or similar to avoid SQL injection attacks, and just bad queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you named "popup" is not really clear: is it another browser window ? An window.confirm or window.alert dialog ? a popup like in [jQueryUI](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/) or [Twitter Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#modals) ?

Let's assume it's a browser window.

You have two possibilities:

1 - Make a single button to close your popup:

```
<button onClick="CloseAndRefresh()">Close</button>
```

2 - Trigger it automatically after N seconds:

```
<script type="application/javascript">
   var n = 5; 
  setTimeout(CloseAndRefresh, 1000*n);
</script>
```

Comment: it is thickbox popup made with jquery and css

Comment: Well, look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11357321/close-thickbox-on-button-click)

Comment: that is for closing the popup, what about redirecting the opener window to the new url?

Comment: You can trigger the redirection with a setTimeout like in my example, once you've called the fadeOut() method.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    CloseAndRefresh();
</script>
```

Although a PHP redirect would probably fit your purpose better.

Here is an article on PHP redirects:

http://php.about.com/od/learnphp/ht/phpredirection.htm

Comment: php redirect does not work in this case because it redirects to the new page in the popup and I do not want that. And about that solution, it does not work. I tried that before I asked here

Comment: Does your function work if you copy and paste into the browser console? What Javascript errors are there if any?

Comment: no error, just a white field because it is supposed to redirect to a url. and it does work if I paste it in a browser console

Comment: You could try using the onLoad property on the <body> tag: <body onload="CloseAndRefresh()">

Answer (score 1):

You can't invoke Javascript functions from PHP as PHP is running on the server, whereas Javascript is downloaded and run on the client, long after the PHP code has executed. You can however print a `<script>` tag where you, in this case, invoke the Javascript function you want:

```
<?php
   echo '<script>(function () { CloseAndRefresh(); } ());</script>';
```

Comment: You need to put it within your PHP code. Remove the `<?php` definition and try to put it just above `} else { echo ...`.